# Passing a variable to .replace, how to make the var work with replace?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following:

```
var r = ':-)'

html = html.replace(/r/g,"<img src=\""+icon_folder+"/face-"+emoticon+".png\" class=\"emoticonimg\" />");
```

I want to add the `/g` so all matches are replaced. This isn't working but if I remove the g and just do:

```
html = html.replace(r,"<img src=\""+icon_folder+"/face-"+emoticon+".png\" class=\"emoticonimg\" />");
```

This does work? How can I get it to work with 'g' so all is replaced? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression syntax

```
/expr/flags
```

is a *literal* syntax. That is, you can't include variables in it any more than you can include a variable inside a string literal. So your expression `/r/g` is not using your `r` variable, it is looking for the letter "r".

The other way to construct regular expressions is with the `RegExp()` constructor:

```
new RegExp(exprString, flags)
```

The parameters are strings, so you can pass variables or string literals.

```
var r = ':-\\)';         // note: need to escape the )

html = html.replace(new RegExp(r, "g"),"<img src=\""+icon_folder+
                        "/face-"+emoticon+".png\" class=\"emoticonimg\" />");
```

The reason your second code-block worked is because you didn't pass a regular expression to `.replace()` - it didn't have the forward slashes of a regex literal, which meant you just passed your `r` variable.

Note that using `new RegExp` often ends up more fiddly than a regex literal, because backslashes have a special meaning in regular expressions but also have a special meaning in strings. So, e.g., `/\d/` would end up as `new RegExp("\\d")` - i.e., the backslash needs to be doubled. (I'm sure you can imagine how messy that can get with a long regex.) In your case your regex contained a closing parenthesis which also needs to be escaped, so your string ends up as `':-\\)'`.

If your `r` variable will always have the hardcoded value you can also say:

```
var r = /:-\)/g;    // note: have to escape the )
```

and just pass `r` to `.replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

fUse the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor with the flags as the second argument:

```
var r = ':-\\)';

html = html.replace(new RegExp(r, "g"),...
```

Comment: You could also use a regex literal, which is arguably cleaner, such as: `var r = /:-\)/g;`